# Why do I get intermittent errors when starting GHCI?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm running Windows 8 and the latest Haskell platform (freshly installed).

I have already checked that all of the required paths are in my `PATH` variable, but when I try to start GHCI, I most of the time get this:

```
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... ghc.exe: : Kan opgegeven module niet vinden.
command line: can't load .so/.DLL for:  (addDLL: could not load DLL)

--WHERE Kan opgegeven module niet vinden --MEANS Can't find the specified module
```

However, once in a while it works ok. Maybe this is caused by a timing problem?

Comment: In my Windows 8 with Haskell Platform 2013.2.0.0, my `PATH` variable (the unique with Haskell references) looks like (in the part for Haskell):

`C:\Users\FooBar\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin\cabal.exe;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\bin`

Are yours like this? Does this problem also occurs with WinGHCi?

Comment: I've got those + C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\mingw\bin in my PATH. WinGHCI also fails in the same way.

Comment: It seems that it's a defect only on GHCi (according to this [GHC bug entry](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3242)) with MinGW origins. However, the problem seems to point to `ghc.exe`: would you mind of trying it with `runghc` and with `ghc`?

Comment: ghc and runghc appear to work correctly.

Comment: So, as reported in the bug ticket, it seems to be a problem in the (dynamic) linking of the libraries from MinGW. I would recommend to (i) reinstall the MinGW or (ii) reinstall Haskell Platform.

Comment: AFAIK you do not need to have Mingw installed before Haskell Platform. Reinstalling Haskell Platform didn't solve the problem.